# Kerning ligatures with font-feature in luatex

Tags: luatex, fontspec, kerning, ebgaramond

Manipulating fonts is somewhat daunting, and usually too much for me, so I restrict myself to a few things. I use Duffner's EB Garamond -- his original version from his [website](http://georgduffner.at). I'm a bit puzzled by the following output:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\directlua
  {fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature 
    {
    name = "ktest",
    type = "kern",
    data = {
    ["t"] = { ["«"] = -80},
    ["f_t"] = { ["«"] = -100},
    ["i"] = { ["«"] = -120},
    ["f_i"] = { ["«"] = -300},
    ["f"] = { ["«"] = -300},
    ["ı"] = { ["«"] = -300},                                           
    }
  }
}

\setmainfont{EBGaramond}
[
Path=./EBGaramond-0.016/otf/,
UprightFont=*12-Regular,
RawFeature=+calt;+ktest,
]

\begin{document}
t« fft« ft« i« fi« f« ff«
\end{document}
```

[image]

Duffner's EB Garamond has nice ligatures **ft** and **fft**, but somehow they don't react to manipulation via font features; the **ff** ligature changes simply by adding a font-feature to **f**, but not the same case with **ft** and **fi**. Trying to reach the glyph directly via **f_t** as it is called when looking for it in FontForge doesn’t do anything.

What is happening here, and how can I kern **fft«** and **ft«**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ft and fft may look like ligatures, but they are not: in this font they are actually  `f`/`ff` followed by a special `t`. So you will have to set up the kerning for this t variant:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\directlua
  {fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature
    {
    name = "ktest",
    type = "kern",
    data = {
    ["t.f_"] = { ["«"] = -300},
    ["f_t"] = { ["«"] = 1000}, %to demonstrate the f_t ligature
    }
  }
}

\setmainfont{EBGaramond}
[
Path=./EBGaramond-0.016/otf/,
UprightFont=*12-Regular,
RawFeature={+calt;+ktest;}
]

\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
 ft« fft« 

\char983114 «  % this is the real ft ligature, 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, `fft`! I is only a small step to `pfft`. ;-)

Comment: The other glyphs in this font are: `i_dotless`, `f_short`, `f._f` and `f._i` (just to save the trouble of having to look them up when stumbling upon this answer and for the sake of completeness ...)